# IOS Push notification errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I've enabled push notifications for my phonegap app inside the `AppDelegate.m` file. The line of code I'm using is from a video tutorial, since I don't really know OBJ-C, and it is giving me a Format String Issue. Here's the code along with the error.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    NSLog(deviceTokenString);}
```

*Format is not string literal (potentially dangerous)*

Knowing Javascript, I kind of understand what they mean by string literally but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the error is appearing on your `NSLog` line, then I think it refers to the fact that the *format string* - the first argument to `NSLog`, which tells it the string you want to output (potentially with substitution tokens) - is a variable, rather than a string literal. You might instead try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken);
```

or if you use `deviceTokenString` elsewhere and want to keep that variable, you can do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", deviceTokenString);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is this if you are wanting to see that the device token was registered:

```
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
```

This will give you the device token information.  Get rid of the string literal because you are converting a string to a string.  No real need to do that.